# SQL Developer will not insert data

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ADD_TO_BLACKLIST(
    P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME IN VARCHAR2,
    T_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
    )
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        E_COUNT PLS_INTEGER := 0;
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO E_COUNT FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE
        WHERE UPPER(EMPLOYEE_USERNAME) LIKE UPPER(P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME)||'%';

        IF E_COUNT = 0 THEN
            INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_TABLE 
            (employee_number, employee_username) 
            SELECT EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, EMAIL FROM EXAMPLE_VIEW
            WHERE UPPER(EMAIL)=CONCAT(UPPER(P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME), '@microsoft.com');
        ELSE
            UPDATE EXAMPLE_TABLE
            SET (EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, EMPLOYEE_USERNAME) =
                (SELECT EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, EMAIL FROM EXAMPLE_VIEW
                 WHERE UPPER(EMAIL) = CONCAT(UPPER(P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME), '@microsoft.com'));

            COMMIT;
        END IF;

        OPEN T_CURSOR For
        SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE_VIEW
        WHERE  EMAIL LIKE CONCAT(UPPER(P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME), '%');
    END;
END ADD_TO_BLACKLIST;
```

This compiles, but when I try to test it with a valid P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME (which I've confirmed to be in the EXAMPLE_VIEW), I do not see any data being inserted.

I am new to PLSQL and not sure how to figure out the value of E_COUNT

The Example_Table DDL is

```
CREATE TABLE "Example_Table"
(   "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "EMPLOYEE_USERNAME" VARCHAR2(250 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "ACCOUNT_STATUS" NUMBER DEFAULT 0, 
    "ACCOUNT_STATUS_LAST_UPDATE" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "BOE_SAFEGAURD_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("EMPLOYEE_USERNAME"))
```

Comment: You don't have a commit after the insert. Move your commit command to just after the "end if" and before the "open t_cursor".

Comment: I added the commit and it still didn't insert the data. I feel that there is something else going on

Comment: Could you try the modification suggested and feedback.

Comment: `"Example_Table"` and `EXAMPLE_TABLE` are two different tables. Which one are you looking in?

Comment: To amplify @WilliamRobertson's comment - when you create a table using a mixed-case or lower-case quoted name such as "Example_Table" you must *always* use the *exact* quoted name when accessing it. Is it your intention to INSERT/UPDATE the table you've shown us (`"Example_Table"`) or a different table (`EXAMPLE_TABLE`)? Try `SELECT * FROM "Example_Table"`. Now try `SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE`. I suspect you'll get different results. Then you're returning a cursor which reads data from `EXAMPLE_VIEW`, but haven't shown us how `EXAMPLE_VIEW` is defined. ???

Answer (score 3):

The issue is in below line,you are not converting the case after concatenation.please modify and try below,

```
 WHERE UPPER(EMAIL) = UPPER(CONCAT(UPPER(P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME), '@microsoft.com'));
```

**EDIT : To prove the theory please find below the details.**

I have tested this and it works,

DDL to create the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Example_Table
(    EMPLOYEE_NUMBER NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    EMPLOYEE_USERNAME VARCHAR2(250 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    ACCOUNT_STATUS NUMBER DEFAULT 0, 
    ACCOUNT_STATUS_LAST_UPDATE TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT BOE_SAFEGAURD_PK PRIMARY KEY (EMPLOYEE_USERNAME));

CREATE TABLE Example_view
(    EMPLOYEE_NUMBER NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    EMAIL VARCHAR2(250 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    ACCOUNT_STATUS NUMBER DEFAULT 0, 
    ACCOUNT_STATUS_LAST_UPDATE TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL ENABLE 
     );
```

DML to populate data to example_view that will be used for the test.

```
insert into example_view values(1,'Test@microsoft.com',1,sysdate);
```

Modified the procedure to add `UPPER` on the rightside of the join for both insert and update conditions and place the `commit` after end if.A good code should have only one commit and that should be at the end of execution before the `exception` block of main begin..end block.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ADD_TO_BLACKLIST(
P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME IN VARCHAR2,
T_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE E_COUNT PLS_INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO E_COUNT FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE WHERE UPPER(EMPLOYEE_USERNAME) LIKE UPPER(P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME)||'%';
    IF E_COUNT = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_TABLE 
            (employee_number, employee_username) 
            SELECT EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, EMAIL FROM EXAMPLE_VIEW WHERE UPPER(EMAIL)=UPPER(CONCAT(UPPER(P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME), '@microsoft.com'));
    ELSE
        UPDATE EXAMPLE_TABLE SET (EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, EMPLOYEE_USERNAME) = (SELECT EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, EMAIL FROM EXAMPLE_VIEW WHERE UPPER(EMAIL)=UPPER(CONCAT(UPPER(P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME), '@microsoft.com')));

    END IF;

   COMMIT;

    OPEN T_CURSOR For
        SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE_VIEW WHERE EMAIL LIKE CONCAT(UPPER(P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME), '%');
END;
END ADD_TO_BLACKLIST;
```

In an anonymous block invoked the procedure,

```
DECLARE
T_CURSOR  SYS_REFCURSOR;

BEGIN 
ADD_TO_BLACKLIST('test',T_CURSOR);

end;
```

Ran a query to check if records are inserted,

```
select * from example_table;
```

Output is below,
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You just need a commit after IF-ELSE condition rather than inside it. I have updated your code along with some other minor updates -

```
create or replace PROCEDURE ADD_TO_BLACKLIST( P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME IN VARCHAR2,
                                              T_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
                                            )
AS
E_COUNT PLS_INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
     SELECT COUNT(*)
       INTO E_COUNT
       FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE
      WHERE UPPER(EMPLOYEE_USERNAME) LIKE UPPER(P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME)||'%';

     IF E_COUNT = 0 THEN
        INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_TABLE 
            (employee_number, employee_username) 
        SELECT EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, EMAIL
          FROM EXAMPLE_VIEW
         WHERE UPPER(EMAIL) = CONCAT(UPPER(P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME), '@microsoft.com');
    ELSE
        UPDATE EXAMPLE_TABLE
           SET (EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, EMPLOYEE_USERNAME) = (SELECT EMPLOYEE_NUMBER, EMAIL
                                                         FROM EXAMPLE_VIEW
                                                        WHERE UPPER(EMAIL)=CONCAT(UPPER(P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME), '@microsoft.com'));
    END IF;

    COMMIT;

    OPEN T_CURSOR For
        SELECT *
          FROM EXAMPLE_VIEW
         WHERE EMAIL LIKE CONCAT(UPPER(P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME), '%');
END ADD_TO_BLACKLIST;
```

Comment: I just tried this and same result. Nothing is being added to the table.

Comment: Then I think better to use debugger now. Just pass the value in debug mode and see why it is not Inserting the data in tables.

Comment: how do I use the debugger? I am new to SQL Developer.

Comment: @softwareisfun - Try the solution posted and feedback.

Comment: @softwareisfun, Can you please check what is the result of SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EXAMPLE_TABLE WHERE UPPER(EMPLOYEE_USERNAME) LIKE UPPER(P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME)||'%';

Comment: @softwareisfun - Will Robertson hit it, but you seem to have ignored it.  _NEVER_ create an object name (table, column, procedure, trigger, etc.) with double-quotes around the name (as you did with your CREATE TABLE statement).  When you do that, it creates a _case-sensitive_ object name, and you will forever have to enclose the name in double-quotes, and with the proper case - every time you reference it.  Leave the double quotes off and you have a case-INsensitive name.  Leave the double-quotes for the MS world and you'll enjoy Oracle more.

Comment: @EdStevens - Very true.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I replaced  the P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME with an actual value and the result was 1

Comment: @EdStevens I copied the DDL from SQL Developer's SQL tab. The table was created using the GUI.

Comment: Exactly, So in that case Only Update will run not Insert, Since it fails the If condition.

Comment: @softwareisfun  - Did you try to modify the where clause as - WHERE UPPER(EMAIL) = UPPER(CONCAT(UPPER(P_EMPLOYEE_USERNAME), '@microsoft.com')). Current one will fail 100% and has to be modified.

Comment: @softwareisfun - If someone created that table in SQL Dev, then they enclosed the name in double-quotes htere, also.  I just tried to create a mixed-case name in SQL Dev, and it would revert it to all upper-case (effectively case-INsensitive) right there on the initial CREATE screen.  The only way to get SQL Dev to create a mixed-case name was to enclose the name in double-quotes when specifiying the name to SQL Dev.  Whoever created that table _forced_ SQL Dev to create it that way.  Bad idea.

Comment: I narrowed it down to my INSERT statement. It looks valid and it runs.

Comment: @softwareisfun - Could you be more specific on what was wrong, I need to knock off my answer if that doesn't make sense.